# not able to get CK editor content with inline CSS

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I m using CKEditor 5 in my angular 14 project. I m not getting inline CSS for my table .
I want to get all content from CK Editor 5 with inline CSS not with class. When i get content from CK editor I want to print this content in pdf. when I am printing right now not able to print proper table due to we don't have inline CSS in this table.